# WP REST API - Issues

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

So I'm trying to work with the WP REST API. Using latest version of WP. I am using this in an external application and testing with Postman.

This is what I want to do:

1. display custom meta fields in the GET posts request
2. GET all posts (no limit)
3. create / update / delete (multiple) meta fields in one API request

Are these things possible with WP REST API? If so, can anyone share some examples?

I know all these work very well with WooCommerce REST API.

Comment: 1. Yes it can, check my profile. I have answered twp questions about this ( accepted ). 2. No maximum is 10 but we still can get total of posts and page (pagination). 3. Never tried it before

Comment: Thanks, but still does not help to do these things with meta. I know we can get meta with posts/ID/meta, what I want to do is get it from /posts with all the posts.

Answer (score -2):

The better way is to use a custom endpoint to achieve this. You must create your own plugin for this...

```
//register different functions for different methods, use parameters in url for GET calls 
register_rest_route('plugin_name', 'your_endpoint', array(
    array('methods' => 'POST',
          'callback' => 'magic_function',           
    ))   
);

function magic_function( $request ) {

    //You can filter the query to get all posts (rest_{$this->post_type}_query)
    add_filter('rest_post_query','my_custom_query', 10, 3);

    $custom_request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/post');
    $response= rest_do_request( $custom_request );

    $response->data['meta_field'] = get_post_meta($response->data['id'], 'meta_field',true);

    return new WP_REST_Response($response->data);
}

function my_custom_query($args, $request){

    //returns all posts in request...
    $args['numberposts'] = -1;

    return $args;
}
```

Comment: thanks but not what I asked for. I made it work by other means. I will post it here if anyone requests.